# entity framework query and is_removed attribute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Im new in entity framework and I want to make service basing on it, but I have a problem with is_removed attrib which is in most of my tables in database.

For instance I have User table and Articles table. Both users and articles can me removed(is_removed=1). I dont wanna work on removed users or articles and in addition I dont wanna create views in my database because unfortunately EF dont give me opportunity to do CRUD operations on views what I need.

So in this situation I have to create queries using is_removed attribute for every table like this(query is returning all articles for user with given user_id):

```
db.User.Single(
    x => x.id == user_id && 
    x.is_removed == 0 
).Article.Where( 
    x => x.is_removed == 0 
);
```

Do you have any solution for it? Is there any way to make this query without using **is_removed** property for each query?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separated project for Linq To Entities stuffes and i would create a public class for all my operations:

Create a class library project
Create the entity classes
Create a class name for example: DALC
Create public properties to the DALC, for example:

```
public IQueryable<Article> Articles { get { return context.Articles.Where(x => x.is_removed == 0); } }
```

This will solve some of your problems but not all and i don't think you can achieve everything what you want.

---

Maybe you can create new properties for your entities: all of the generated entity classes are partial and that means you can extend any of them whith new properties, methods, fields.

For the User class:

```
public IQueryable<Article> ActiveArticles { get { return this.Articles.Where(x => x.is_removed == 0); } }
```